# scanf getting stuck

Tags: c, scanf

Im a beginner in C. Im using scanf function in my c program and its getting stuck and the program moves ahead only when i type exit.
The part of the code in which Im facing problem is:

```
while(fread(&emr,recsize_emr,sizeof(emr)/recsize_emr,fp)==1)
{
    if(emr.emr_id==emr_id)
    {
        printf("%s %s %s %d %d %s %s %f \n\n",emr.fname,emr.lname,emr.company_name,emr.emr_id,emr.agt_id,emr.pol_start_date,emr.pol_end_date,emr.amount);
        printf("Enter New First Name, Last Name, Company Name, EmployerID, AgentID, Policy Start Date, Policy End Date, Amount : ");
        scanf("%s %s %s %d %d %s %s %f \n",emr.fname,emr.lname,emr.company_name,&emr.emr_id,&emr.agt_id,emr.pol_start_date,emr.pol_end_date,&emr.amount);
        fseek(fp,-recsize_emr,SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(&emr,recsize_emr,sizeof(emr)/recsize_emr,fp);
        break;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In

```
scanf("%s %s %s %d %d %s %s %f \n");
```

the final `" \n"` consumes all whitespace after the `float` has been read. That means the `scanf` only returns after it received a non-whitespace character after the `float` - for that character to reach the program, you typically need to enter a newline after it.

If you remove the final whitespace from the format string,

```
scanf("%s %s %s %d %d %s %s %f");
```

the `scanf` returns as soon as it finished reading the `float`. Then it will leave the newline - or whatever character follows the `float` in the input` in the input buffer, so it is probably necessary to clear the input buffer before further scans.